# How to get selected FileView item

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have created in Visual Studio a MFC project which includes a cFileView, CDockablePane class.

[image]

As the image shows a item is selected and the menu is open. If I now klick on open the ON_COMMAND message will be called.
My problem is, how can I retrieve file name from the selected item. I have used

```
const MSG* pMsg = GetCurrentMessage();
HWND hWnd = HWND(pMsg->lParam);
```

In the pMsg pointer I can not find any item name "2020m7", only some x y coordinates.

How I can get the selected item name?

Answer (score 1):

It is a CViewTree class. As in the image above you can see, the Item is selected.

```
HTREEITEM hItem = m_wndFileView.GetSelectedItem();
CString iText = m_wndFileView.GetItemText(hItem);
```

Therefore with the CViewTree pointer you can get the selected item and the item text via the HTREEITEM.
Nothing from the message is required.